# Migrate Local projects to TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

I have about 14 projects (different solution files) that are sitting on local dev box. Just got connected with TFS 2010. How do I move these projects to TFS 2010 (without getting vss involved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181280(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008 installed, then the first thing you need to do is install Team Explorer 2005 or 2008 from the TFS 2005 or TFS 2008 media.  You'll then need to install the TFS 2010 forward compatibility GDR ([2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/team_foundation/the-visual-studio-2005-forward-compatibility-update-is-available), [2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20060719041159/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en)) For the forward compatibility information, see [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/teams_wit_tools/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005).

If you have Visual Studio 2010 installed, then Team Explorer is installed already.

You then go to View, Team Explorer.  Right click on the little "+" button to connect to a server and enter your details.

The you can either add your files by right clicking on the solution in solution explorer and sayying Add to Source Control or by going to the Source Control Explorer and pressing Add then selecting your files.

Comment: Martin, I did all that before posting the issue. I am actually on the last step you suggested. When I Right Click on the Solution Explorer and click on  "Add Solution to Source Control" I see a wizard to set it up on VSS "Add SourceSafe Database Wizard".

Comment: I found the answer on this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181280(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Here is another good link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253064(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Very easy: You just add them to TFS. Right click on the files and choose "Add" from the menu and afterwards check-in. Then they are in the TFS. Of course that doesn't include automatic deployment via TFSBUILD etc.

Comment: 1. I opened my solutions as usual with studio 2005. 2. I dont see Add > Check-in from the solution explorer or project or individual file(s).

Comment: See Martin's answer above. You need to install Team Explorer to alleviate all TFS functionality within Visual Studio.

Comment: I found the answer on these links.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181280(VS.80).aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253064(v=VS.80).aspx